I have a problem when installing netbeans version 11 or 17 or 21 with the jre version of jdk, I used jdk 8 with jre, JVM print hs_err_pid17992
This is the log that JVM print, ¿How I can resolve in order to install netbeans version 17 with jdk 8?
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:144), pid=17992, tid=0x000000000000208c
guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_202-b08) (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.202-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
I´m trying install netbeans 17 with jdk 8

The official page states:

The Apache NetBeans 17 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially support running on JDK 11, 17 and 19.

So JDK 8 won't work.
